# What does 'socieza' mean?

Tags: hispanoamérica, palabras-raras, letras-de-canciones

Is it even a word?

I heard it in [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfi6h14QjcI&t=3m43s)

> Arrogando con sus besos
>
> sus caricias y su cuerpo qué malvada
>
> Le diste la luna a una estrella
>
> y mira como te paga
>
> Te ha jugado una **socieza**
>
> no merece tu perdón.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's a bad transcription. The actual word being sung is *sucieza*, which isn't proper Spanish also, but it's derived from *sucio [dirty]*. So the line:

> Te ha jugado una sucieza no merece tu perdón.

can be roughly translated as:

> She played you dirty, she doesn't deserve your forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, it's not proper Spanish. The proper noun derived from adjective "sucio" would be "**suciedad**". Even then, one wouldn't say it like that. Perhaps "Te ha jugado una **vileza**" or "Te ha jugado una **mala pasada**".

Answer (score 0):

"Socieza" is definitely a local dialect, but probably he is trying to say "Te ha jugado sucio"